Android: Former Connection Fragment create blows up on newer IDE
This is older code I am attempting to migrate to Androidx on a more-or-less forced basis as the older exoplayer has been yanked by Google off the Internet and as such I'm forced to migrate it forward as the older release will not build even with a backdated SDK.  It compiled and ran previously (and has for several years; I'm using the APK on a current Pixel) but after going through all the older compat library includes and changing them out for the androidx ones the IDE will not accept it as it won't let me return the two possible intents depending on the calling arguments.  Attempting to explicitly typecast the returns doesn't work either (the IDE complains that cannot be done)
public class DisplayImage extends SingleFragmentActivity {
    private static final String EXTRA_HOST = "net.cudasystems.android.homedaemon_mcp.host";
    private static final String EXTRA_LOCATION = "net.cudasystems.android.homedaemon_mcp.location";
    private static final String EXTRA_NAME = "net.cudasystems.android.homedaemon_mcp.name";
    private static final String EXTRA_VIDEO = "net.cudasystems.android.homedaemon_mcp.video";

protected static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, String Host, String Location, String Name, String Video) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, DisplayImage.class);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString(EXTRA_HOST, Host);
        extras.putString(EXTRA_LOCATION, Location);
        extras.putString(EXTRA_NAME, Name);
        extras.putString(EXTRA_VIDEO, Video);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected ConnectionFragment createFragment() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String Host = extras.getString(EXTRA_HOST);
            String Location = extras.getString(EXTRA_LOCATION);
            String Name = extras.getString(EXTRA_NAME);
            String Video = extras.getString(EXTRA_VIDEO);
            if ((Video != null) && (Video.length() > 0)) {
                return DisplayVideoExoPlayerFragment.newInstance(Host, Location, Name);
            } else {
                return DisplayImageFragment.newInstance(Host, Location, Name);
            }
        }
        return null;    // It better not!
    }

This particular fragment is called with two possible argument sets; one requests an image while the second requests a video.  Both go into the same player, which has historically worked just fine, but now the IDE thinks that's not acceptable.
What it claims it wants for the returned type is another SingleFragmentActivity that launches the main application; that code is here and has no flagged errors; the other two which are complaining are calls to display things (which can be backed out of, of course):
public class HomeDaemonActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity {

    private static final String EXTRA_HOST = "net.cudasystems.android.homedaemon_mcp.hostname";
    private static final String EXTRA_NAME = "net.cudasystems.android.homedaemon_mcp.name";

    public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, String Hostname, String Name) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, HomeDaemonActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_HOST, Hostname);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_NAME, Name);
        return intent;
    }

    @Override
    protected HomeDaemonFragment createFragment() {
        String Host = (String) getIntent()
                .getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_HOST);
        String Name = (String) getIntent()
                .getSerializableExtra(EXTRA_NAME);
        return HomeDaemonFragment.newInstance(Host, Name);

    }

}

Do I need to refactor the code at the upper level where it is being called completely or is there a way to cast the return so that the previous code will be accepted?
Thanks in advance.
This returns "Incompatible types" for both of the above "Display" calls which are the actual fragments I need to create (depending on the arguments of course.)
